# Display Glitch in Cytoscape

Tags: java, cytoscape

I have installed the latest version of Java as well as Cytoscape. Whenever I open Cytoscape, there seems to be a display bug or glitch after around 2-3 minutes of normal work. This display bug seems to happen whenever I hover the cursor around let's say Tools --> Merge or File --> Import.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both Java and Cytoscape a couple of times and the display glitch still persists.

Could this be a problem of graphic drivers?
My PC Specs are:

Windows 10 64bit
Graphics: NVIDIA RTX 2060ti 6GB
RAM: 16 GB
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5

Cytoscape Version: 3.9.1
Java Version: 11.0.6

I have also shared screenshots of the display glitch.

Thanks

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esv3A.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enJgy.png)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answer can help you. I have solved this problem on my laptop equiped with a AMD chipset by downloading an old Cytoscape version 3.7.2 (which has the "CX support" app pre-installed). Then, in the "App" tab I have uninstalled this app and restarted Cytoscape. Now, the problem seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your problems.  As you suggest, the only time I've seen that it's been due to graphics driver issues.  Can you try upgrading to the latest NVIDIA drivers and see what happens?

Comment: I have the latest NVIDIA drivers and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this quesion, use your integrated graphics to run cytoscape, do not use NVIDIA Graphics.

Comment: There is no integrated graphics on my pc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can be sure, the problem appears on your graphics